# Angular 10 + Nativescript Multipart File Upload

Tags: angular, typescript, file, http, nativescript

I'm trying to upload a file from a phone file system using Nativescript 7. I've tried both *nativescript-background-http* and *nativescript-http-formdata* aswell as *HttpClient* imported from *@angular/common/http* but none of this methods seem to work. My server is running RocketChat ([this is the API](https://docs.rocket.chat/api/rest-api/methods/rooms/upload)) and i can successfully upload files using Insomnia REST Client. This is my first try with Angular HttpClient:

```
const formData = new FormData();
var file = this._audioFolder.getFile("file.mp3");
formData.append("file", file, "file.mp3");
this.httpClient.post<any>("https://myserver.com/api/...", formData, {
  headers: {
    "X-Auth-Token": "my_token",
    "X-User-Id": "my_id",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001"
  }
}).subscribe((resp) => {
  console.log(resp);
}
```

Which returned the error: *Argument of type 'File' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'* when I appended **file** to formData. Then I tried to convert my file to Blob using this code:

```
getBase64String(file: fs.File) {
  const data = file.readSync();
  //data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(0); iOS
  return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(data, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

And then

```
const blob = new Blob([base64file], {type: "audio/mp3"});
formData.append("file", blob, "file.mp3");
```

Which was accepted by the FormData append method, but the response returned the error:

```
"error": {
    "success": false,
    "error": "File required"
}
```

Then found [this](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative/blob/develop/app/lib/methods/sendFileMessage.js) solution on GitHub and was interested on this part:

```
formData.append('file', {
  uri: fileInfo.path,
  type: fileInfo.type,
  name: encodeURI(fileInfo.name) || 'fileMessage'
});
```

But returned the error: *Argument of type '{ uri: string; type: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.*

My guess is that the class File derived from nativescript/file-system is quite peculiar and can't be considered as Blob. I've also tried to convert it into buffer array using **atob** function, but the method is undefined.

After that, I've installed *nativescript-background-http* and followed [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-background-http) example, but i got an error here:

```
var task = session.uploadFile(file, request);
```

telling me that an instance of Observable cannot be invoked without *new*. The very same happens with *nativescript-http-formdata* on that line:

```
let fd = new TNSHttpFormData();
```

which is quite confusing since it's a very [basic](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-http-formdata/) operation and *everyone* who use this plugin must instantiate that class.

Now, what else can I try to fix/workaround those problems? I can't modify the backend APIs, but I can try **any** method you can think of to upload a simple file using http post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution: as written [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http), if you are using **Nativescript 7** you have to run

```
tns plugin add @nativescript/background-http
```

instead of

```
tns plugin add nativescript-background-http
```

Surprisingly, it's not mentioned on the official [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-background-http) page.